# update in pre save hook

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a user schema like this

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  }, 
  cardIds: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'cards',
  }],
})
mongoose.model('users', userSchema)
```

I'm attempting to do two things in the pre save hook for user: first, saving each card with the user id and second, adding the `cardIds` to the User. My code:

```
const Card = mongoose.model('cards')

userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (this.cardIds.length === 0) {
    cardList.forEach(async card => {
      const newCard = await new Card({ ...card, user: this })
      this.cardIds.push(newCard) // this is not working
      newCard.save() // this is working
    })
  }
  next()
})
```

This will add each card into the `cards` collection with the correct `user._id`, however, each user will still have an empty array for `cardIds`.

The way I save the user is (omitting error handling/validation for convenience):

```
app.post('/users/new', async (req, res) => {
  const newUser = await new User({ username: req.body.username })
  await newUser.save()
  return res.json({ message: 'User created successfully' })
})
```

Comment: Please post query for creating user

Comment: actually the `userSchema` also has another property `username`, so in the `post` route I just do `const newUser = await new User({ username: req.body.username }); newUser.save();`

Comment: please update your question instead of commenting

Comment: I just updated it, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a javascript code `this.cardIds.push(newCard)` to push an element to an array but It doesn't do anything to your mongo database...

Therefore, In order to update an array in mongodb you need to use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator

```
userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (this.cardIds.length === 0) {
    cardList.forEach(async card => {
      const newCard = new Card({ ...card, user: this })
      const saveNewCard = await newCard.save() // this is working
      const updateUser = await User.update(
        { _id: this._id },
        { $push: { cardIds: saveNewCard._id }}
      )
    })
  }
  next()
})
```

Comment: Hi, @Ashnish. Where are you grabbing `User` from in `User.update` ? Thanks